# How can I avoid the browser re-parsing my SPA's javascript files when I open a new window for the site?

Tags: javascript, performance, window

I have a large SPA (single page application), which in the development environment is 70 MB uncompressed javascript code. I'm using react, material-ui, and many other open-source components for a large commercial intranet application platform. The initial page load takes about 10 seconds, 7 of those are used in parsing the application's javascript code.

This application's main purpose is to be used in Network Operations Centers to manage devices on the company's network. One of the SPA's features is that it allows the user to Pop Out a window for the current application page (using `window.open`), which is highly useful in a NOC as users will often have multiple monitors attached with different views displayed on each one. (Perhaps this makes my app no longer qualify as a SPA, but that's off-topic, so let's not belabor that point.)

The issue is that these popouts take nearly 10 seconds to load as well, even though it uses the exact same JS files with no cache-busting components to the src urls. I would expect these popouts to only take 1 to 3 seconds to load since 100% of the code is shared between it and the parent window and the only thing that is potentially different is data/state.

How can I keep from having to re-parse all of this JS code, and reduce my load time for these popouts?

Comment: I've done some quick searching, and it looks like no current browser caches compiled JS code. I don't know if that makes any difference, but I basically want to share code between the parent window and the popout without having to reload everything.

Comment: you simply can't. Javascript is interpreted language. as of this comment, you cannot.

Comment: Time to consider implementing some lazy loading and some server side rendering

Comment: Oh, we do lazy loading... the page pop-out gets a pretty little loading indicator until the app code finishes parsing and re-compiles.

As for being an interpreted language, that's a sticky comment and I won't go into it other than to say you may want to look into how browsers interpret JS code, turn it into bytecode, optimize and then compile it. But, apart from that, yeah, I believe you are correct about "you cannot."